# How to set HELM_CACHE_HOME env var (or exclude caching) when running Helm template command?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a specific request of running Helm template command in environment with filesystem access read-only on the regular location where Helm cache is stored (I'm executing this command inside AWS Lambda).
An error that I get is:

```
Error: mkdir .cache: read-only file system
```

Now, to overcome this problem, my idea is to:

- either disable cache when running specific command
- point HELM_CACHE_HOME to location which is not read-only (mounted location from EFS file system)

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a way to disable a cache and following command doesn't work (even when running it locally, without any lambda environment):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/helm/.cache/helm
HELM_CACHE_HOME=/tmp/helm/.cache/helm helm template elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch --dry-run

ls -la /tmp/helm/.cache/helm
total 0
```

Any way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I've figured out that I've used incorrect environment variable.

For Helm 3, correct variable is:

```
XDG_CACHE_HOME
```

Reference: https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#xdg-base-directory-support

However, even if this works, docs say that HELM_CACHE_HOME should also work (which is not the case).